# SQL FreeTextTable [Key] Join to VarChar ID

Tags: sql

I have a search facility on my website which ranks matches using the RANK field on a freetexttable. I have been joining the KEY field to my product IDs with no problem as both a integers. However I have since had to convert my product ID to a varchar in order to start using alpha numeric values. Whatever I seem to do I can no longer get the KEY field to match to the product ID field. This is what I have so far.

```
USE [database]
SELECT distinct ft.id, ft.title, ft.was, ft.[desc] AS 
productdescription, ft.price, ft.sortcost, ft.hidden, ft.discount, ft_IDX.RANK, ft_IDX.[KEY]
FROM dbo.products as ft
left JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(products, [desc],'bomber',50) ft_IDX ON CAST(ft.id AS VARCHAR(10)) = CAST(ft_IDX.[KEY] AS VARCHAR(10))
INNER JOIN [database].[dbo].[product_channel] ON [database].[dbo].[product_channel].[productid] = ft.id 
WHERE  (ft.hidden = 0) and (ft.superhide = 0)
```

Also will the KEY field start using alpha numerics when I start using alpha numeric product IDS also? If not then this exercise is probably pointless as my search will never return products with alpha numeric IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue was something to do with the full text Index Cataloging. I recreated the catalogue and it solved the issue.

For anyone who gets the same issue, To do this I removed the old catalogue from the table by going to design view, right clicking and selecting full-text index. Then I deleted the current one. I then went to storage > right clicked the catalogue and re-applied to catalogue to the products table and the fields I wanted cataloging. This re-catalogued the IDs (even though they were varchars) and worked.